# How to make multiple partials use the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a page that separates users into different categories based on the sport they chose during signup. I am currently trying to do it with two different partials. The issue I am running into is that I can't have two separate partials use the same model. How would I do this?

Comment: If you show us your code we can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. Partials are just a way to split up html.erb code in multiple smaller files and possibly reusing them between various views.

If you want the separation in one view, and are new to rails, I would try it without partials until it works (maybe just for two categories).

Then, you can factor out the repeated code into partials and reuse them, and of course you can use all models there. Maybe you're just not aware of the possibility to pass parameters into partials? Like, if @feed_item was the variable set by the controller (or any other variable)

```
<%= render 'shared/feed_item_raw', feed_item: @feed_item %>
```

and then in the partial simply refer to it with `feed_item`

Comment: First I'm trying to modify the sample app in Michael Hartl's rails tutorial. The issue is that I can't have two partials use the same  model information. I get a "undefined local variable or method `user'" error. I thought the partial automatically inherited the model of whatever folder it was in

Comment: partials or views don't inherit models. in the view, all controller instance variables are available. for the partial, you can pass variables as I noted in my answer above, which is what you need to do if you need access to the model there.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
render :partial => 'partial_path', :locals => {:user => your_user_object}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one model, clients, which have different states. I needed to render them on different parts of the same page

```
    <%= render(partial: "active_clients", collection:@active_clients) || "No active clients yet." %>
    <%= render(partial: "inactive_clients", collection:@unactive_clients) || "No inactive clients yet." %>
```

Those go to their respective parts of the view.

Then in my view/clients folder I created two different partials, because each partial is slightly different.

```
 _active_clients.html.erb
 _inactive_clients.html.erb
```

one of those partials looks like this inside:

```
    <li>
        <input class="checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox"/>
        <%= link_to "#{active_clients.firstname} #{active_clients.lastname}", dashboard_path %>
    </li>
```

the other partial doesn't have "checked" in the checkbox. That's the only difference.

in my clients_controller index action I've seperated the two arrays like this:

```
 def index
     @active_clients = current_trainer.active_clients
     @inactive_clients = current_trainer.inactive_clients
 end
```

The final piece is inside the trainer model...

```
 def active_clients
     self.clients.where(status: true)
 end

 def inactive_clients
    self.clients.where(status: false)
 end
```

This works like a charm for me. I hope that helps...